# Why is it my database has no tables after the migration is successful?

Tags: laravel

```
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (2,098.36ms)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table (2,513.18ms)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (2,176.21ms)
Migrating: 2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table
Migrated:  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table (2,733.81ms)
Migrating: 2021_07_31_010300_create_facilities_table
Migrated:  2021_07_31_010300_create_facilities_table (3,177.34ms)
Migrating: 2021_07_31_010400_create_providers_table
Migrated:  2021_07_31_010400_create_providers_table (10,980.40ms)
Migrating: 2021_07_31_011439_create_provider_offices_table
Migrated:  2021_07_31_011439_create_provider_offices_table (4,954.14ms)
Migrating: 2021_07_31_012004_create_provider_affiliations_table
Migrated:  2021_07_31_012004_create_provider_affiliations_table (7,707.26ms)
Migrating: 2021_07_31_012323_create_selection_codes_table
Migrated:  2021_07_31_012323_create_selection_codes_table (3,326.91ms)
Migrating: 2021_08_06_043903_add_image_url_to_providers_table
Migrated:  2021_08_06_043903_add_image_url_to_providers_table (1,554.82ms)
Migrating: 2021_08_07_230223_create_provider_logs_table
Migrated:  2021_08_07_230223_create_provider_logs_table (2,070.62ms)
Migrating: 2021_09_03_122036_add_state_to_providers_table
Migrated:  2021_09_03_122036_add_state_to_providers_table (844.32ms)
Migrating: 2021_09_18_053003_create_sessions_table
Migrated:  2021_09_18_053003_create_sessions_table (6,154.56ms)
```

Comment: What is in your env file?

Comment: Did you check the correct database?

Comment: yes i already checked it

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: What OS? How/using which tool do you check? phpMyAdmin? Is it set to the same non-default values you have entered? (Port 3306 is the default port)